# Insert images into a database

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to upload an image to a mysql database, but when I upload the image I receive the message of confirmation, but when i check my database the image row is empty, what am I doing wrong?

```css
<?php include "connection.php"; ?>
<?php
$n=$_POST["num"];
$t=$_POST["texto"];
$i=$_POST["imagem"];
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILE['$i']['tmp_name']));

if ($connect->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE servicos SET texto='$t', imagem='{$image}' where nmr=$n" ;

if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "informação atualizada";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}

$connect->close();
?>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="formulario" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" target="apresenta" method="post" action="menu2.php" style="position:absolute; top:70;left:10
border:thin; border-style:none;">
<label> Atualizar dados </label><br>
Numero:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="num" value=""><br>
Texto:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="texto" value=""><br>
Imagem:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" name="imagem" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" value="limpar">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using addslashes(file_get_contents(? See here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Why do you want to increase the database size? It's not good practice to store the files in the database, you should take help of file system to store them on the server. If you still want to save the files in the database you first need to convert them to base64 format or in any other format we can save in database.

Comment: A common way to handle this is to store the image in the file system and then store just the path to the image in the database

Comment: @fredrover is totally right, store the images on your server in a directory and only store the url in database. 
Also, you should take a look at http://bobby-tables.com to learn about SQL injection. Your code isn't safe at all and your database can be hacked in a few seconds...

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 how do i convert?

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the comments stating "You shouldn't store files in tables because...", this is what works (with PHP 7):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    var_dump($_FILES);
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test", "root", "");
    $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test_img (cont) VALUES (?)");
    $stm->execute(array(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileinput']['tmp_name'])));
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File: <input type="file" name="fileinput"><br>
    <button name="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Possible error sources:

- `$connect->query($sql) === TRUE` should be `$connect->query($sql) !== false`
- The entry you want to `UPDATE` does not exist
- `imagem='{$image}'` is a rather "hacky" way do insert variables, use concatenation: `$sql = "UPDATE servicos SET texto='".$t."', imagem='".$image."' where nmr=".$n;`

Hope this helps.